# API: How can I remotely check if two data sets are identical, without sending all data across the API?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, synchronization

I'm building an API to allow remote systems to synchronise **millions** of rows in a data table (one-way).  The systems run different databases at each end (my receiving system is SQL Server but the sending system is SAP/Hana) so they can only communicate via an API.

Using only methods on an API, how can I determine the differences in data rows between the two systems and ensure they are always in sync?

One idea I had is to provide a list of IDs (primary keys), followed by some kind of "check" value or LastUpdatedDate which the remote systems can then use to find out which records they need to add or update. However if there are 10 million rows+, is there any way to avoid sending all 10 million keys each time I want to synchronise the databases?

Are there any protocols I can copy ideas from which do a similar thing?  I know IMAP for example, uses an approach similar to that above, but is poor at handling "millions" of emails.

**EDIT** (additional info):

- No records can be deleted on the source system - so I don't need to handle that.
- There will be 20 million new rows each year, up to a max of circa 150 million.
- Old records can occasionally be updated and need to trigger a re-sync.

Comment: If you use some sort of versioning, meaning where you aren't updating rows only inserting *new* rows with a "inserted time" columns, then you could check the max(ID) or max(timeColumn) against each other and only compare this one row. I'd use the ID in this case since it'd be the primary clustered key.

Comment: Alas, the old rows sometimes get updated without me being able to change the ID. That's a limitation of the source system.

Comment: Ouch. One idea to test would be add a computed column to the tables with the hashbytes of their concatenated values (of all columns). Then, just check the hash of the entire column against the same of the other table. You can use SHA2_512 and should avoid collisions. Just an idea... could suck for performance, I'd just test against the dataset. Not sure how sap/Hana handles this type of function so this is speaking from SQL Server.

Comment: Theoretically, LastModifiedDate should work just as well as a hash, as long as the source system *always* updates it.

Comment: Only thing i was thinking about that is what if they were updated at the same time, but different values were inserted/updated? Just depends on your granularity i supposes.

Comment: The sync is one way only... so that can't happen. Essentially I just need a 'backup' of the data from the remote system.

Comment: Ah, then last_updated timecolumn is where i'd probably go. I'm sure there are gaps in this though. Maybe move this to dba.stackexchange.com. They'd be better.

Comment: Have you looked at SQL Server Change Data Capture? This might help you avoid some work.

Comment: @DavidButtrick That looks like it would be useful, if the source server was SQL, but unfortunately the flow is from SAP to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that there is no perfect way to do this without sending the full data across the wire.

However you can cheat.  The [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) utility solves this problem by hashing entire ranges and comparing.  If there is a difference it breaks into chunks and repeats until it finds minimal diffs to send.  The reason why this is cheating is that hashes of different things are not *guaranteed* to be different - they are just likely to be different.

In your case I would suggest having hashes of each row, then hash the concatenation of those hashes over ranges based on the original ID.  If there is a block without differences, you can ignore it.  If it has differences and is large, then split into `k` blocks (you can experiment on `k`) and repeat.  If it has differences and is fewer than `N` rows (experiment on that as well) then send the list of hashes, and you know what rows to compare.

For efficiency I would precompute the hashes per row like @scsimon suggested, and have a combined index on `(id, hashed)`.  That way all of the queries to pull back and hash blocks will JUST be range queries on the index data structure, and don't even visit the large table.  Trust me, this should make a very significant performance difference.